# Reading xml file on some condition

Tags: c#, xml

I want to use a xml file which is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pages>
    <page name="Default.aspx">
        <method name="Login_click">
            <message code="0" description="this is a test description">
                <client code="0000000000" description="this is a description for clent 0000000000" />
            </message>
        </method>
    </page>
</pages>
```

Now I want to create a function like below

```
 public static string GetAppMessage(string pageName, string methodName, string clientCode, string code)
 {
        var xmlFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Theme.xml");
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(xmlFile);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientCode))
        {
           //go to node who page name to pageName
           //and read the vlue   
        }
        else
        {
            //read for a particular client code
        }
 }
```

How can I do this.

### Edit 1

Do I need to loop through each node or can I reach to a particular node directly and find the decedent nodes.

like below

```
foreach (XmlNode chldNode in doc.ChildNodes)
{

   ....
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9494/Manipulate-XML-data-with-XPath-and-XmlDocument-C

Comment: you can use linq for this.
see this it will help out:http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2014/09/how-to-deserialize-xml-using-linq.html

Comment: What do you mean by "*//read the value*"? What is the value you're interested in given the XML posted?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of XmlDocument you can use XDocument and LINQ to xml:

```
var xmlFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Theme.xml");
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
var xmlPage = (from page in xmlDoc.Descendants()
              where page.Name.LocalName == "page"
                    && page.Attribute("name").Value == pageName
              select page).FirstOrDefault();
if (xmlPage != null)
{
    //do what you need
}
```

Comment: Alternative is [XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/d271ytdx(v=vs.110).aspx), but damn, its ugly. (Yet still more readable than regexp)

Answer (score 0):

When you use XmlDocument and you know how the XML-file will look like (I mean you know the names of the nodes where the information is inside) then you could do something like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path);
XmlElement root = doc["NameOfRootNode"];

if (root != null)
{
     //For nodes you just need to bypass to get to another subnode:
     XmlNode node = root.SelectSingleNode("nameOfAnotherNode");  

     //For nodes you actually want to do something with, like read text, attribute etc.
     if (node != null && node.SelectSingleNode("nameOfOneMoreNode") != null)
     {
          var xmlElement = node["nameOfOneMoreNode"];
          if (xmlElement != null) 
          {
               //Read from the xmlElement you selected and do something with it...
          }
     }

     //...
}
```

With SelectSingleNode or SelectNodes you can maneuver to a specific known node and can read the InnerText or an Attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath to get `<page>` element by it's `name` attribute, for example :

```
string xpath = "//page[@name='{0}']";
XmlNode page = doc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format(xpath, pageName));
//and read the vlue
```

Basically, above XPath look for `<page>` element having `name` attribute equals `pageName` parameter.